# no IPv6 peers connecting to my node

Tags: nodes, peers, peer-discovery

`getnetworkinfo` says IPv6 is working on my node:

```
{
"name" : "ipv6",
"limited" : false,
"reachable" : true,
"proxy" : "127.0.0.1:9050"
}
```

Yet why don't I get any IPv6 peers connecting to my node? Sometimes I get many connecting to it, but right now I have only IPv4 peers.

Comment: Does your proxy endpoint support IPv6?

Comment: @Bitcoin: I don't know why it even says IPv6 is using a proxy. I don't want it to. It has said that before, though, when I did have IPv6 peers.

Comment: @Bitcoin (127.0.0.1:9050 is my Tor proxy, which is working, since a few of my peers are Onion addresses.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue was that `bitcoind` was discovering my wrong IPv6 address. (It mistook my link IPv6 address for my public one.) I set `--discover=0` and set my IPv4 and IPv6 addresses manually with `--externalip`.